# Existence and uniqueness ODE Internal Interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x-y}, \space y(2)=2$

When looking at this I assumed that it was continuous because it seems like a perfectly acceptable answer. $\sqrt{0}=0$ there are no issues. Somewhere I read something about an internal interval and limit. Why is existence not guaranteed?

Comment: What do you mean by “$y=2$,$x=2$”? Remember that you seek a **function** $y(x)$. The constant function $y(x)=2$ is not a solution.

Comment: I just meant when you put those inputs in for each variable they equal to zero

Comment: You can't insert a specific value of $x$ into an ODE, that's just meaningless. You need to find a **function** $y(x)$ such that the ODE holds for **all** values of $x$.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to solve the equation?

Comment: No. Simply see if it is continuous about the point if f(x,y) is continuous and the partial derivative with respect to y is continuous about the points given then a solution exists and it is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence theorems usually only apply to open domains where the right side is continuous.

Obviously, the term under the root limits the domain by its requirement to be positive. The problem is that $(x,y)=(2,2)$ is a boundary point of the domain, not an inner point of the open set $\{(x,y): x>y\}$. One can repair this deficiency by extending the domain, for instance via
$$
y'=\sqrt{\max(0,x-y)}.
$$
This is now continuous on all of $\Bbb R^2$ so that solutions exist locally. Now you have to determine in what direction the boundary of the original domain is crossed in the initial point.